# Django with mqttasgi, how to update the db with contents of received messages

Tags: python, django, mqtt, asgi

I have a Django project that reads messages from mqtt using mqttasgi

I can see the messages in the mqttasgi output

```
mqttasgi --host localhost --port 1883 myapp.asgi:application   

2023-01-10 18:08:55.380206 -- Received a message at topic: test/device/online   
With payload: b'true'   
And QOS: 1
```

what I want to do is search for device in the message and then update the model just like I do with the web interaction

I tried importing the model into the consumer

```
import json 
from datetime import datetime 
from mqttasgi.consumers import MqttConsumer 

import django 
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

django.setup()

from .models import Device

class MyMqttConsumer(MqttConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.subscribe('test/#', 2)
    
    async def receive(self, mqtt_message):
        print(f"{datetime.now()} -- Received a message at topic: { mqtt_message['topic'] }")
        print(f"With payload: { mqtt_message['payload'] }")
        print(f"And QOS: { mqtt_message['qos']}")
        (site, devicename, topic) = f"{mqtt_message['topic']}".split('/',2)
        device = Device.objects.get(name=devicename)
        if topic == 'online':
            if mqtt_message['payload'].decode('UTF-8') == 'false':
                device.online = False
                device.save()
            else:
                device.online = True
                device.save()
        pass
    
    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.unsubscribe('test/#')
```

but as soon as I do that then mqttasgi complains about it

`django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

How do I modify the code so that the db update works?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but just try adding `await` before `device.save()`

Comment: no sorry that does not work, looks like it fails at `device = Device.objects.get(name=devicename)`

Comment: did you try `device = await Device.objects.get(name=devicename)`?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when attempting to perform a synchronous operation (which blocks execution) within an asynchronous context, such as in this case where you are using async/await to handle MQTT messages in a consumer.

To fix this, you need to ensure that database operations are performed asynchronously. This can be done using the `sync_to_async` function from the `asgiref` library. These functions allow you to convert a synchronous function to an asynchronous one and vice versa.

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
```

...

```
device = await sync_to_async(Device.objects.get) (name=devicename)
await sync_to_async(device.save)()
```